# How to remove duplicate rows from a join (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to get only unique rows from three tables. How I can do it?

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM l_req
LEFT JOIN p_req ON (p_req.uid = l_req.uid)
LEFT JOIN r_req ON (r_req.uid = l_req.uid)
WHERE l_req.uid = 100931362
```

Tables architecture:

```
Table l_req

id column2 column3 uid

1     2      3      100931362
2     3      4      100931362
3     4      5      100931362

Table p_req

id column2 column3 uid

1     6      5      100931362
```

etc

Query result:

```
id column2 column3 uid              id1  column21 column31 uid1
1     2       3     100931362        1       6       5       100931362
2     3       4     100931362        1       6       5       100931362
3     4       5     100931362        1       6       5       100931362
```

=> I have a duplicate rows from a JOIN.

I need result like this:

```
id column2 column3 uid              id1  column21 column31 uid1
1     2       3     100931362        1       6       5       100931362
2     3       4     100931362        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3     4       5     100931362        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: You can't do that with a left join. If your conditions match multiple times, they're going to join multiple times too. Can you explain why you need null values for the subsequent results? If its for performance reasons, perhaps you should look at selecting from multiple tables instead of a join, union queries or even temporary tables for a better fit.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? Maybe someone can provide a helpful answer with another solution.

Comment: @scrowler, I need only unique values, so I want to get a NULL value. I hope you can help me with valid query.

Added more information to question.

Comment: How can you tell that the `NULL`s should be in the rows with `l_req.id = 2` and `l_req.id = 3`, and not in the row with `l_req.id = 1`? What's special about that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your table structures look almost identical, there are other options for you than just joins. Here's a possible solution using [unions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

Set a manual field name identifying which table the rows come from so you can distinguish after the union, because the results will all look the same otherwise.

```
SELECT 'l_req' AS table_name, id, column2, column3, uid FROM l_req WHERE uid = 100931362
UNION ALL
SELECT 'p_req' AS table_name, id, column2, column3, uid FROM p_req WHERE uid = 100931362
UNION ALL
SELECT 'r_req' AS table_name, id, column2, column3, uid FROM r_req WHERE uid = 100931362
```

I'm also assuming here that your `r_req` table has the same structure as the others. You can expect a result from this query that might look like this:

```
table_name  id  column2 column3 uid
l_req       1   2   3   100931362
l_req       2   3   4   100931362
l_req       3   4   5   100931362 
p_req       1   6   5   100931362 -- this is your extra result original from join
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
Select id,column2,column3,Uid from
(
SELECT *
FROM l_req,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id,column2,column3 ORDER BY id ASC) AS RN
LEFT JOIN p_req ON (p_req.uid = l_req.uid)
LEFT JOIN r_req ON (r_req.uid = l_req.uid)
WHERE l_req.uid = 100931362
) AS T

Where RN = 1
```

**(Or)**

```
Select Case when RN = 1 Then id Else Null End,
       Case when RN = 1 Then column2 Else Null End,
       Case when RN = 1 Then column3 Else Null End,
       Case when RN = 1 Then uid Else Null End
(
SELECT *
FROM l_req,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id,column2,column3 ORDER BY id ASC) AS RN
LEFT JOIN p_req ON (p_req.uid = l_req.uid)
LEFT JOIN r_req ON (r_req.uid = l_req.uid)
WHERE l_req.uid = 100931362
) AS T
```

Hope this help you